# Compare std::variant with int using C++20 <=> is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, std-variant

Since the `std::variant` is not allowed to compare with one of its alternative types in the standard library, I am implementing the compare function using C++20 `<=>` operator:

```
template <typename... Args, typename T>
constexpr auto operator<=>(const std::variant<Args...>& v, const T& t) {
  return std::visit([&t](const auto& u) -> std::partial_ordering {
    if constexpr (requires { u <=> t; }) return u <=> t;
    else return std::partial_ordering::unordered;
  }, v);
}
```

But when I testing the above function with my own defined `std::variant`:

```
using Variant = std::variant<double, int, std::string_view>;
constexpr Variant v1{1.0};
constexpr Variant v2{1};
constexpr Variant v3{"hello"};
static_assert(v1 < 2);
// compile error
static_assert(v2 < 2);
static_assert(!(v3 > 2) && !(v3 < 2) && !std::is_eq(v3 <=> 2));
```

[**The second assertion couldn't compile**](https://godbolt.org/z/o3vbE1), GCC says:

```
<source>:19:17: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
   19 |   static_assert(v2 < 2);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:24:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'operator<=><double, int, std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >, int>(v2, 2)'
<source>:19:17: error: '<anonymous>' is not a constant expression
```

Why is `v2 < 2` not a constant expression? or it's just a **GCC bug**? Weirder, when I change the second assertion to compare with `double`, this can compile:

```
static_assert(v2 < 2.0);
```

**Update:**

[**Clang can pass three assertions, but MSVC can only pass the third assertion**](https://godbolt.org/z/fnEfdE), **it seems MSVC also has a bug.**

Comment: The 1st example is a compiler bug. The 2nd example is ill-formed (your `visit` lambda returns different types for different invocations), although still a gcc bug for ICE-ing (ICE is always a bug).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example reduces to:

```
#include <compare>

// this one is okay
static_assert(std::partial_ordering(std::strong_ordering::less) < 0);

// this one fails with non-constant condition
static_assert(std::partial_ordering(1 <=> 2) < 0);
```

Everything here is obviously a constant expression. The fact that `strong_ordering::less` can be converted to `partial_ordering::less` just fine while `1 <=> 2` can't be (on gcc) suggests that this is a bug in the compiler, rather than the library.